# Django: LDAP search results disappear

Tags: ajax, django, ldap

Why in the code below, does the global `direktorie` return the correct data in the `login()` debug template, yet when I try to access the same variable from `autoname()` it says the list has a length of `0`?  I don't reference `direktorie` in any other places in `views.py` -- or anywhere else for that matter. (All of the code below is merely an attempt to discover what I'm doing wrong. I don't really care about the length of the returned list. I just want to know it's being seen and has roughly the right number of entries.)

```
from django.http           import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts      import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
import json                      # JSON for jQuery AJAX autocomplete
from   eldappery import *        # LDAP for jQuery AJAX autocomplete

direktorie = []

##############################################################################

def login(request):
  """LDAP Login routine"""
  global direktorie

  if request.method == "POST":                   # If submitted...
    if request.POST["username"] and request.POST["password"]:
      username = request.POST["username"]
      password = request.POST["password"]
      LDAPfeed = dapperize(username, password)   # ...login
      if LDAPfeed:
        direktorie = fetch_names(LDAPfeed,"")    # ...get everybody
        ls  = locals()                           # DEBUG!
        gs  = globals()                          # DEBUG!
        return render_to_response("debug.html",
                                  {"ls": ls,
                                   "gs": gs})    # DEBUG! Works! (direktorie full)
      else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")
  return render_to_response("login.html",
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))

##############################################################################

def autoname(request):
  """Auto-complete names"""
  global direktorie
  if request.is_ajax():
#   results = [{"id":    5,
#               "label": 5,
#               "value": 5}]                # DEBUG! Works! (5 in template)
    results = [{"id":    len(direktorie),
                "label": len(direktorie),
                "value": len(direktorie)}]  # DEBUG! Doesn't work! (0 in template)
    data = json.dumps(results)              # Convert to JSON string
  else:                                     # No results returned!
    data = "fail"                           # Error...
  mimetype = "application/json"             # MIME type = JSON
  return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)       # Send JSON back to web page

##############################################################################
```

Comment: I have no idea what `from eldappery import *` does. FWIW, ["While it is valid to use from `module import * at` module level it is usually a bad idea"](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#at-module-level)

Answer (score 0):

Loose the line -

```
global direktorie
```

You don't need to declare the variable `direktorie` as being global since you're not assigning a value to it. Python will assume any variable on the right hand side of an assignment is global (unless it's appears on the left hand side of an assignment, elsewhere in the function).

Also you may want to check that your webserver is running your app using a single process. If it's set up for multiple processes, eg with an apache configuration directive like -

```
WSGIDaemonProcess yoursite.com processes=2 threads=15
```

then you're going to hit problems with global directives.

Answer (score 0):

The desing of the view's of django, do not allow you to pass global variables between the views. If you want to pass, data between views, you need to use ajax, to send the data in a get or post requests.

```
def index(request):
    print 'helou'
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'lala': 'lala'})

    #index.html
    # <script type='text/javascript'>
    #  obj = {type:'get', url='/test/view0', data: {tamangandapio:'yeah'}, type='json',
    #         response: function (){ console.log(response) }
    #         }
    # $.ajax(obj);
    # </script>

def view0(request)
  #here you see the data send by the jquery code below
  print request.GET
  res = {'success':'i got it'}
  return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(res), mimetype='application/javascript')
```